# Object creation of views and share data between view in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am new to iOS.I am recently stuck with a problem.
I have a view A and View B. View A has a navigation controller. view A has a button to switch to B.When i am clicking this button every time B creates a new object. how can i track this object to share data between this two view.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by you want to track the view?

Comment: Do you want to pass data from A to B?

Comment: You should watch the beginning of Lecture 7 in the Stanford iOD course on Protocols: https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/coding-together-developing/id593208016

Comment: And you should read the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/q/5210535/1445366 since they basically cover everything that would be discussed here.

Comment: How to pass data or some times the object between views.Actually i want to know what is happening behind the graphics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

You could have a property of B, that A sets before you push. (NSDictionary, Array, String etc)
This not the best way however it would work.

```
UIViewController *viewB = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[viewB setMyProperty:@"some data!"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewB animated:YES];
```

You could also use NSNotificationCenter to pass the object to the next view.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:index]
                      forKey:@"index"];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myNotification"
                                      object:self
                                      userInfo:dictionary];
```

The way I usually handle this is to setup and object that holds my data with an associated protocol initialized in my AppDelegate. Then any view that needs to read/write something just grabs a Pointer to that object and runs with it.

```
@class AppData;

@protocol AppDataProtocol

- (AppData*)theAppData;

@end
```

in the View you can grab the pointer with this.

```
-(AppData*)theAppData {

    id<AppDataProtocol> theDelegate = (id<AppDataProtocol>)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    AppData* theData = (AppData*)theDelegate.theAppData;

    return theData;
}
```

and this.

```
 appData = [self theAppData];
```

You are then able to easily access any property of appData.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)fnButtonA{

ViewB *vcB = [[ViewB alloc] initWithData:DataToB];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:vcB animated:Yes];

}


In ViewB.m edit the init function to 

-(UIViewController *)initWithData:(NSMutableDictionary*)data
```